# VSCode, Powershell, cmdlet not found (Netlify) 'netlify init'

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, init, netlify, powershell-cmdlet

After installing netlify via npm (*globally*) in VSCode (*Windows 10*), when I type `netlify init` in the Powershell terminal it says that it can't find the cmdlet. What's wrong with my computer? Please help.

Comment: is that app file in your search path? if not, then you need to use the fill path when referring to it OR fix your search path. [*grin*]

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm a newbie when it comes to these kind of things. I'd appreciate your help. (npm commands and npx create-react-app, for example, work without any issue)

Comment: @David Is your shell inside VScode CMD, PowerShell or WSL?

Comment: PowerShell (inside VSCode)

Comment: @David - try using `$env:Path.Split(';') ` to see the paths that windows will search for things that are not in the current path. if your added software is not there ... then you will need to either add the software location to your path OR use the full path when referring to the software.

Answer (score 1):

**From the powershell terminal in vsCode run:**

```sh
npm list -g --depth 0
```

You should get a result similar to below with all your global installs

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
`-- npm@6.9.0
```

#### If you don't see `netlify-cli`, in the powershell terminal run:

```sh
npm install -g netlify-cli
```

Then run `npm list -g --depth 0` again and if it installs, you should see it in the list

```sh
C:\Program Files\nodejs
+-- netlify-cli@2.11.23
`-- npm@6.9.0
```